# Why does an assignment operator have to return anything

Tags: c++

So far from what I have read is that an assignment operator always returns a reference.
My questions is why does it have to return anything when a void could simply do the job.

For instance something like this

```
class foo
{

   void operator=(const foo& that)
   {
      this->myint = that.myint;
      .....
      .....
   }
}
```

I hope this question makes sense ?  Since it satisfies `a = b`

**Update :** I  understand from the answers that the primary reason for returning is to satisfy expression like a=b=c . Could anyone please explain why the above wont work for `a=b=c` ? Since operator= of a is called and copies b onto a and operator of b is called and copies c onto b ?

Comment: How else are you going to do `a = b = c;`?

Comment: (Yes, I know, most people don't use this, but it's the reason!)

Comment: @MatsPetersson could you tell me why the above wont work with a=b=c ?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm not suggesting this is how C++ should have done it, but `a = b = c` could have been just syntactic sugar for `b = c; a = b`. That's how it is in Python.

Comment: @MistyD: Because "B = C" would do the assignment and it would return "void", and then it would end up with "a = void", which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: `std::insert_iterator<>::operator=()` is worth considering.

Comment: @MistyD: Obviously, if `b = c` doesn't return something that can be assigned to `a`, then `a = b = c;` will not work. I wasn't there when C was designed, and C++ just does the same thing as C, but for user-defined objects.

Comment: An overloaded assignment operator can return whatever it wants. It's just a matter of convention, familiarity, expectation and experience that returning a reference to the assignee has turned out to be useful. Make sure you understand that there's a difference between *an* assignment operator and *the* copy-assignment operator, just like there are many constructors, but only some are *copy* constructors.

Comment: Dont know why the negatives ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's so that you can write something like the following. Let's say the class `foo` has a default constructor, and one that takes an `int` as an argument (just using the default shallow copy assignment operator):

```
foo A(10);
foo B;
foo C = A = B;
```

If the assignment operator didn't return anything, this type of assignment wouldn't work (if `A = B` didn't return a reference to `A`).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be that way, but c++ (and c) assignment operators are defined as doing this, so within those languages they have to.

Comment: -1 this explains nothing and is completely useless.  Of course there is a reason behind every decision. "It is that way because it is that way" doesn't teach the OP or future visitors anything.

Comment: I see what you mean, I'm trying to say that this is mostly a historical effect from the way c was designed, rather than a necessary aspect of a programming language. I do not believe that this feature is in c++ because it is needed or particularly useful.

Comment: Perhaps, but an answer should at least describe the how assignments are expected to work in C++, regardless if the motivation behind it.